# How to convert multiple JSON files from different folders into different dataframes

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I have several folders with a specific name that contain several JSON files. What I want is to put the JSON files for **each** folder together and convert each set of JSON files into a dataframe with the name of the folder. Then I would like to put the different dataframes into one list.

For example, in the path '/in_my_path' I have 3 folders with the names 'name1', 'name2' and 'name3' respectively. Each folder contains several JSON files. I would like to create a list with 3 dataframes with the names "name1", "name2" and "name3".

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

`purrr` has a few super useful functions for traversing vectors and lists and applying custom functions to each item.  The example code below does not convert the JSON to a data frame so you'll need to play around with that.

```
# Path to folders which contain JSON files.
path <- 'my_path'

# List folders, excluding the containing folder.
folders <- list.dirs(path) %>%
    .[. != path ]

# Traverse folders, reading JSON contents of each folder.
json_list <- folders %>%
    purrr::map(function(folder) {
        json_files <- list.files(
            folder,
            '\\.json$', # pattern that identifies .json files
            full.names = TRUE
        )

        # ingest JSON data - note further processing required to convert list to data frame here
        json_data <- json_files %>%
            purrr::map(~jsonlite::fromJSON(readLines(.x)))

        return(json_data)
    }) %>%
    rlang::set_names(
        purrr::map_chr(folders, ~strsplit(.x, '/')[[1]] %>% tail(1)) # set names of list items to folder names
    )
})
```

Comment: It gives a list of empty elements